# Deploy the scheduler application on multiple servers without running all of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, devops

I have a python app that have scheduler and i want deploy it on multiple server.

Problem:
If I deploy my app to multiple servers, all schedules run, but I only need one of them.

*** I don't want to define a field in the database and find out through it whether the scheduler should run or not, I am looking for another solution to not save anything anywhere****

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

disable the scheduler and try to schedule it via a microservice from outside. As for example if you want to do this opensource you can use airflow and prefect. If you are on AWS you can use EventBridge, lambda
Microservice for this purpose.

Comment: have any solution dose not use 3rd parties?